# extra brace when use \csname in \clist_set:No

Tags: expl3, csname

clist is not set appropriately with `\cs_if_exist_use:c` or `\csname ... \endcsname`, it seems that there is extra braces. If I use `\clist_set:Nx`, error occurs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\expandafter\def\csname test-1\endcsname{a,$\alpha\dotsb$,b}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_test_clist
\NewDocumentCommand {\test} {}
  {
    \clist_set:No \l_test_clist {\cs_if_exist_use:c {test-1}}
    \clist_use:Nn \l_test_clist {*}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\clist_set:No` expands `o`nce, but you need more than one expansion of `\cs_if_exist_use:c` to get the result.  Try `\clist_set:Nf`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It works! But if I want to keep the contens of the control sequence unexpanded, e.g. there are some commands such as `\linewidth` that depends on the context, how can I make it expand just twice to `a,$\alpha\dotsb$,b`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, `\cs_if_exist_use:c` should be used with a `cs`, not a `clist` (it works because their implementation happens to be similar, but you can't rely on that).
Also unless a function is documented to completely expand in *n* steps, you have no guarantee that it will expand in *n* steps, and if it does, it may change eventually (for instance `\char_generate:nn` and `\prg_replicate:nn` are documented to expand in two steps, so you can rely on that).

To get what you want you can use an `x` expansion on `\clist_if_exist:cT`, then protect the *value* of the `clist` from expanding by using `\exp_not:v`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\expandafter\def\csname test-1\endcsname{a,$\alpha\dotsb$,b}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_test_clist
\NewDocumentCommand {\test} {}
  {
    \clist_set:Nx \l_test_clist
      {
        \clist_if_exist:cT {test-1}
          { \exp_not:v { test-1 } }
      }
    \clist_use:Nn \l_test_clist {*}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, `test-1` is a bad name for a clist

Answer (score 4):

The `o` variant will do a *single* expansion step. You need much more to get at the clist.

If you want to use symbolic names for clists, do it in a more proper way. You shouldn't count on `\def\zzz{a,b,c}` to be a “real” `expl3` clist.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineclist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l__zhiyuanlck_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l__zhiyuanlck_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand {\test} {m}
 {
  \clist_if_exist:cTF { l__zhiyuanlck_#1_clist }
   {
    \clist_use:cn { l__zhiyuanlck_#1_clist } {*}
   }
   {OOPS}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineclist{test-1}{a,$\alpha\dotsb$,b}

\begin{document}

\test{test-1}

\test{test-2}

\end{document}
```

[image]